# Using regex with fileinput gives error in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.5

Here is my code that I am using to replace some text in a file:

```
for line in fileinput.input(the_file,inplace=True):
    sys.stdout.write(line.re.sub('Begin.*?end', new_data))
```

This gives me the following error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 're'

I thought that maybe I can use the `re.sub`part directly like this:

```
sys.stdout.write(re.sub('Begin.*?end', new_data))
```

but that gave me the error:

> TypeError: sub() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

How can I use regex with `fileinput` in Python to properly search and replace text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
sys.stdout.write(re.sub('Begin.*?end', new_data, line))
```

The signature for [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub) is `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

Comment: It works but there is a problem. The  new file now has one empty line after each of its original line.

Comment: Does it matter if the text I am searching for is only in one line and not all of them?

Comment: To fix the empty line issue, replace the above with `sys.stdout.write(re.sub('Begin.*?end', new_data, line.strip()))`. As for if it matters where the text is located, I am not the one to make that decision, that's up to you

Comment: Thanks khredos but it has stripped all the lines now. :) I just want to keep the lines in their original format.

Comment: @SanJeetSingh This is no longer part of the original question, but rather is a result of further implementation. I encourage you to ask a new question regarding how to replace part of a string with another.